# iphone IOS too high for Xcode version

Tags: ios, xcode6, osx-mavericks, ios8.4

My iPhone is on IOS 8.4, but my Xcode version only supports up to 8.2. Is there a way to get around this to put it on my iPhone? My computer is super old (white 2008 macbook), and can't run Yosemite to get the next Xcode update.

Comment: Looks like you need an upgrade!!!

Comment: RIGHT! i juts can't afford anything else! @gagarwal

Comment: You probably cannot just fire up the app from Xcode and have it run on the device like usual, but if you think of the device like some random beta tester, I would have thought that would have worked. Perhaps build the app and drag it from the "Products" folder into the Devices window (in the "installed apps" list). Or use TestFlight. If you google how to install apps on beta testing devices, you might find some good guides on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

put a ssd in your macbook and force the upgrade to Yosemite https://www.thinkclassic.org/viewtopic.php?id=425